# Linear Reference initial datasets

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data, linear-referencing

I am trying to work with Linear Reference system as I found It in ArcGis website: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003m00000002000000
But I'm losing something in the backgrounds, maybe in the initial datasets preparing. The metric calculations results shows nothing in the table field.

I am doing this task using the road shape from Open Street Maps shapefile, also I got some Garmin GPS coordinates obtained from specifics and aleatory points in some of these roads in my selected area(two to three points at least per road).

These coordinates were imported to a shapefile and my intention is to use these coordinates as a real reference points to create routes with a linear metric system using ARCGIS tools to create, calibrate(to extrapolate after and before and interpolate between points) to help me locate a thousands of events (that is specified in kilometers in the event table) along those roads instead I have to go in any event place to pick GPS coordinates for each event.

I pasted some screens of the initial datasets I got so far. I pointed the M_field to "shape*" field in calibrate process, is It correctly?

The fisrst screen: The original table from OpenStreet;
The second one: after routes created;
The third: the coordinates table.

[image: OpenStreet dataset]

[image: Created Route, before calibration]

[image: Coordinates Points]

Comment: The best practice is to use points at the end of roads to calibrate them, i.e. convert them into routes. Point at the start has m=0, at the end m=length. Make sure you are using solid text string as road ID. Units must be the same, i.e. metres

Comment: So should I create a new text field with "m" value explicit, right? I.E. If I got a coordinate from a specific kilometer of the road, then road name should be: SP-332 and coordinate of kilometer 129 should be stored in a "M" field with value 129? @FelixIP

Answer (score 1):

1. Create points at the ends of road SP-322.
2. In double type field of the points set 0 for start point and road length for end point.
3. Use points to calibrate roads into routes
4. Create events along the road using your table, thus record in your table SP-322, 3555 (m) will become a point 3555 m from the start of road SP-322

Comment: In the calibration tool a measure field value is required for points layer, and I figured out that I don't have the m-value available for the calibration tool works. I've searched for a solution to create the m-field in the points layer that came from GPS and imported as a text file to ArcGis. Is possible to create this field for a point layer? @FelixIP

Comment: step 3 will make m-features from your roads. It will use data from points at the ends